# Upload entire directories using Uploadify (or something else)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload, uploadify

I am using uploadify along with ASP.NET to upload files to my server. At the moment I have to recreate the folder structure and upload the images in batches per directory.

Does anyone know of a way of using Uplodify or any other tool that would allow me to select a folder and upload the entire directory?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd need a Java-based uploader, similar to Facebook's one.

Comment: Can you suggest one? I have done a quick search and can't find one that jumped out. I don't really use facebook so not sure of that one :)

Comment: I count vouch for any from personal experience but it looks like a Google search for "html folder upload java" returns some good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided I will upload a zip file containing the structure and deal with it that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with javascript. You should take a look at solutions, that use client java or flash.

Comment: I know it isn't possible with Javascript. The one I am using currently is flash but I would like to try allowing folder selection without having to zop the whole lot up.